# does the facedook-sdk physically download the user profile image?

Tags: android, facebook, image, file, facebook-sdk-3.0

I need the file of the image of the user profile. i need to upload it to my server.

Im using the facebook-sdk and I know that facebook passes the `URL` and a `ProfilePictureView`, but i need the `File`!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I  think you can download the profile image from facebook graph api call. https://graph.facebook.com/" + fbId+ "/picture?width=" + size + "&height=" + size
Get the fb id form the facebooksdk and make a call to download the image. This is what i did.. Hope this helps.

Comment: thats the URL of the picture. but using the sdk im already able to see the picture but im not able to save it. As your saying i would have to download again the picture using the facebook URL? isn't it redundant?

Comment: dont use ProfilePictureView. Just use Imageview. Dont use the sdk to load profile image. Download it from the url and save it in sdcard.